# When making a form, what's the difference between required in html and checking it later in php?

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, security

I'm new to web development and I don't know whether it's better to check that user filled out all the fields in a form by using "required" or to check it later using php with empty() and then return user to the front page. What are the upsides and downsides of each method?

I tried both of them and the only difference I could think of is the "Please fill out this field" box when using the html way.

Comment: Downside of client-side validation is, that it can easily be circumvented. Or might not be "supported" to begin with - whatever I use to send a request to your server, must not necessarily be a "browser".

Comment: Actually it's a good practice to do both: Check in backend with PHP and frontend with required attribute or js functions. Why? for backend: current technologies depend more on APIs so it's more likely that your PHP script will be called from different html pages, so it's good to allways verify at server side. for frontend it deals with UX, like presenting a message "Please fill..." as you sais

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom line here is that your server-side code cannot cannot trust *anything* it receives from the client-side.

A web application receiving a HTTP request has no way of knowing whether that request came through a user-interface where some validation was applied to the data before sending, or if someone modified that user interface to remove some checks (which is easy in a browser if you have a little knowledge of the Developer Tools), or if (for example) it came from some sort of bot firing requests directly at your server, or if someone simply opened up PostMan and made the HTTP request by hand.

Therefore, in terms of security and validation, you **must** implement server-side validation and security procedures if you want to ensure the security and validity of your application and its data.

Client-side validation is great for improving the user experience and performance of your application (so that the user doesn't have to wait for a round-trip to the server before they get feedback on the validity of data they are trying to submit), but since it easily can be bypassed or disabled you cannot rely on that alone to protect your application.

Answer (score 1):

Setting required in html tells users that a field is required and prevents someone from accidentally submitting a form with an empty field. However, people can still send the form with a missing field manually, by creating a request outside of a browser. The PHP should be able to handle that, though it can be as simple as returning an error.

In general, you should use client-side validation like required to tell users what to do, and server-side validation to prevent unintended behavior by bypassing the client.

Answer (score -1):

Those are both necessary for making a secure and robust app. That is front-end and back-end validation.

The front-end validation makes it so the user cannot accidentally fill unwanted data into the fields shown. That ensures that users are using the app as intended.

The back-end validation makes sure that the values that are coming in are always values that are expected. What makes this different is that people can bypass front-end validation quite easily, and thus they will abuse this by inserting bad data in your app which can break your whole app completely.

Comment: I'd dispute this somewhat. `Those are both necessary`....only server-side validation is _necessary_ for security. Client-side validation is purely a nice-to-have from a security point of view, since it's trivial for anyone with a little bit of knowledge to bypass it. The server needs to be able to keep the app safe without any client-side code. Client-side validation is very important from a UX (user experience) point of view, but it has no impact on security at all, and very little on the "robustness" of the app, except in cases where it may help to make other client-side code simpler.

Answer (score -1):

It is necessary to check the validity of the data received from the user on the server, so you must set conditions for it on the server so that invalid data does not enter the database.
Also, to improve the user experience, it is better to have controls in html in addition to the server, this will even make the server not always check and reject the wrong request, so use both of them together.